# Expo (react native) como crear un boton de recuperar contraseña por firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, app, expo

Desarrollé un login con registro e inicio de sesión de una aplicación pero no se como hacer para que la contraseña se envíe por correo electrónico o se envíe un enlace de recuperación, tengo entendido que firebase tiene esa funcionalidad disponible pero Authentication > Templates > Recuperar contraseña me aparece algo como: Asunto
Reset your password for %APP_NAME%
Mensaje
Hello,

Follow this link to reset your %APP_NAME% password for your %EMAIL% account.  (un link) If you didn’t ask to reset your password, you can ignore this email.

Thanks,

Your %APP_NAME% team    ¿como se supone que eso se conecta con mi aplicación de react native?

```
 async function handleForgotPassword() {
try {
  await sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email);
  Alert.alert('Correo enviado', 'Se ha enviado un correo electrónico para restablecer tu contraseña.');
} catch (error) {
  console.log('Error al enviar el correo electrónico:', error);
  Alert.alert('Error', 'No se pudo enviar el correo electrónico para restablecer la contraseña.');
}
```

Tengo eso en un modal y cuando ingreso el correo me aparece que no se pudo enviar el correo electrónico ¿debo configurar algo en mi App.js?